# What does a digit in the margin mean in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have just migrated from Eclipse to IDEA as the IDEA of choice. Since I have been working with Eclipse some time and did not want to learn all short commands again, I decided to use Eclipse keymapping. However now I have an issue. The comment keymap would be

Ctrl+Slash for line comments

Ctrl+Shift+Slash for group comments

This does however not work as expected:

Ctrl+Slash does not work at all

at Ctrl+Shift+Slash a digit appears in the margin

[image]

However, Ctrl+NumPadSlash works (divide).

This is not the case for Ctrl+Shift+NumPadSlash, which minimizes all blocks instead (This is expected though since the keymap is defined like that).

So the quesion, what does the digit in the margin mean and does anyone know how to solve this?

I use idea 2016.3.2, RedHat 6.6, Swedish keyboard (which means Slash is typed as Shift+7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The square box is a `bookmark with mnemonic`

[image: Bookmark Dialog Image]

Comment: Right, this kind of solves both questions. When I know what it is I will be able to customize this as I wish. I start to feel the IDEA settings would be more convenient than the eclipse settings for IDEA. Thanks!